# Why thread waiting until another thread is done

Tags: java, multithreading

I need use timer in my application, which doesn't block application, so I make class timer and create thread with timer in `class1`:

```
Thread cas = new Thread() {
     public void run(){
         casovac = new timer(); 
     }      
};
cas.start();
```

And then, I call method of timer in `class2`:

```
piskvorky.casovac.startTimer();
```

But, all classes waiting until is done thread with timer, where is:

```
public void startTimer() {
    zapnuto = true; 
    while(zapnuto) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }   
        System.exit(-1);                
    }
}
```

Why all classes wait and how make them not waiting?

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization block

```
Thread cas = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        casovac = new timer(); 
    }      
};
cas.start();
```

is in a separate thread but this does not mean the timer runs on that thread itself.

*Also note that it should be 'new Timer()' not 'new timer()' unless you are using your own 'timer' class. In which case the name should be changed to 'Timer' anyway.*

You are still calling `piskvorky.casovac.startTimer()` inside the main thread which blocks the application when you use `Thread.sleep(20000)`.

Instead you should move the `startTimer()` method call onto the separate thread so

```
Thread cas = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        casovac = new Timer();
        casovac.startTimer();
    }      
};
cas.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your thread only creates the timer, but doesn't start it. You start it in `class2`. Try instead:

```
Thread cas = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        new Timer().startTimer(); 
    }      
};
cas.start();
```